# Returning different types from a method using Python protocol type hint throws type-checking error

Tags: python, protocols, type-hinting, python-typing, pylance

I'm building something that has to process objects corresponding to several different data formats but that basically does a similar set of operations on each one. I'm using `protocol`s from the `typing` module to do this.

This example illustrates what I'm trying to do - a method that conceptually does the same thing (returns some input) but which in practice needs to accept different data types as inputs (either `int` or `str`). I've got one concrete class for processing `int` and another for `str`. I'm doing this by invoking a method in a property setter method because that reflects the structure in my actual project (no idea if this is important, but including it here just in case):

```
import typing

class MyProtocol(typing.Protocol):
    
    _output: typing.Any
    
    def my_method(self, some_arg: typing.Any) -> typing.Any:
        raise NotImplementedError

    @property
    def my_property(self) -> typing.Any:
        raise NotImplementedError

    @my_property.setter
    def my_property(self, some_arg: typing.Any) -> None:
        pass

class MyClass():

    _output: int

    def my_method(self, some_arg: int) -> int:
        return some_arg

    @property
    def my_property(self) -> int:
        return self._output

    @my_property.setter
    def my_property(self, some_arg: int) -> None:
        some_value = self.my_method(some_arg)
        self._output = some_value

class MyOtherClass():

    _output: str

    def my_method(self, some_arg: str) -> str:
        return some_arg

    @property
    def my_property(self) -> str:
        return self._output

    @my_property.setter
    def my_property(self, some_arg: str) -> None:
        some_value = self.my_method(some_arg)
        self._output = some_value
```

I've then got a function definition that orchestrates the whole process, and I've used my protocol definition in a type hint:

```
def process(class_name: str) -> MyProtocol:
    if class_name == 'MyClass':
        input = 3
        obj = MyClass()
    elif class_name == 'MyOtherClass':
        input = 'stuff'
        obj = MyOtherClass()
    else:
        raise NotImplementedError

    obj.my_property = obj.my_method(input)

    return obj
```

pylance is shouting at me here because:

```
Cannot assign member "my_property" for type "MyClass"
  "int | str" is incompatible with "int"
```

I don't understand this - surely `int` is definitely compatible with `int | str`?
Perplexingly, if I do this:

```
def process(class_name: str) -> MyProtocol:
    if class_name == 'MyClass':
        input = 3
        obj = MyClass()
        obj.my_property = obj.my_method(input)
    elif class_name == 'MyOtherClass':
        input = 'stuff'
        obj = MyOtherClass()
        obj.my_property = obj.my_method(input)
    else:
        raise NotImplementedError

    return obj
```

the pylance error goes away, even though it is doing exactly the same thing just with a bit of repetition. Can anyone shed some light on what is going here? How can I fix the type hints in the class definitions to stop this from happening? Or is pylance flagging something it shouldn't?

Comment: You expect `pylance` to store cross-dependencies like "these vars are both int or both strings" - and none of python typecheckers does something similar. And types compatibility is not symmetrical, so `a is compatible with b` is absolutely not equivalent to `b is compatible with a`, and you cannot assign `str|int` to variable of type `int`. All what type checkers knows at error line is that your `obj` is `MyClass | MyOtherClass`, and `input` is `str | int` - this situation is not type-safe. Finally, you should probably be using generics to be DRY, or is it just a very simplified example?

Comment: @SUTerliakov thanks for your comment. This is a simplified example of what I'm trying to do - generics look useful but aren't suitable for my case, I just didn't want the actual logic to obscure the problem I was having. 

Noted on the fact that type checkers don't handle cross-dependencies - to get around this I've just brought the conditional into a separate function which I then call in my main function, and that seems to have solved this without needing to call the method twice (and pylance seems happy with this, all types appear consistent). Thanks for your help!